# How to connect to AWS EMR via AWS QuickSight

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr, amazon-quicksight

I am trying to connect to AWS QuickSight with AWS EMR via Spark JDBC.

I gave hostname of AWS EMR Master node and Port 18080, but I am not sure about the username and password.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/66Acv.png

Even when i click on validate i am getting the below error:

> [Simba]SparkJDBCDriver Error initialized or created
>   transport for authentication: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized
>   SSL message, plaintext connection?.

Couldnt find anywhere on what needs to be inputted in the fields. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out. here are the steps:

Start thriftserver in EMR server.

```
sudo /usr/lib/spark/sbin/start-thriftserver.sh
```

The port for Spark Thriftserver will be : **10001**

Either enable this port in EMR inbound setting or use SSH Tunnel to connect to spark via JDBC.

Username and password could be anything.

SSL needs to be unchecked in QuickSight to connect.